# SELECT * Returns 1 Record, But SELECT COUNT(*) Shows 3k+ Records

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I imported a csv file that had more than 3k records into a database table in SQL Server using the Import Wizard.  I do not receive any errors, and the import wizard shows success, with 3217 records imported.  If I run the following statement, I get 3217 records:  `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl`.  However, if I try `SELECT * FROM tbl`, only one record is returned.  What's going on here?

Using SQL Server 2014 Management Studio.

Answer (score 4):

So I figured this out less than a minute after I hit post, despite thinking about it and googling for a bit.

So the problem is that I ran a procedure earlier that deleting some duplicate values in a table using `SET ROWCOUNT 1` and a WHILE loop.  I realize that I didn't actually set rowcount back to zero (`SET ROWCOUNT 0`) after the break in the loop.  After doing that, I can see all the records now.

Answer (score -2):

It's impossiable,SELECT * FROM tbl will return 3K records.

Comment: It's entirely possible as the other answer states. `SET ROWCOUNT x` will limit the resultset returned to `x` rows.